# Tensorflow tokenizer rows reduction / Beginner

Tags: tensorflow

Once I tokenized text with tensorflow tokenizer, I got a diminished amount of rows - 50 (!) instead of 5320 as in the original file. No duplicates/ empty rows were included in the text.
Has it ever happened to you? Command was very simple:

```
A = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(B)
A = pad_sequences(A, maxlen=90)
```

As you probably figured out I am a very begginer,thus would be grateful for any advices!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide minimum reproducible code with sample data to replicate and  understand the problem.